# Looping a dynamic scrollable element both directions (up and down)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are lots of solutions for looping the entire page, but I'm having trouble adapting them to specific elements with fixed heights.  Here is what I have:

```
    var el = this;
    var originalHeight = el.children().first().outerHeight() * el.children().length;
    var dup = el.contents().clone();
    el.append(dup);

    el.scroll(function(){

        var scrollPosition = el.scrollTop();

        if( scrollPosition >= originalHeight ) {
            el.scrollTop(0);
        }
    });

};
```

The above works perfectly for scrolling down.  As soon as I add the `else` statement, things go bad.  Not only does the loop up not work well, it causes the loop down to jump.

```
if( scrollPosition >= originalHeight ) {
    el.scrollTop(0);
} else if (scrollPosition < x) {
    el.scrollTop(y)
}
```

I have tried various things for x and y with no luck.  Again, it technically "works" but it jumps a lot.  I need this to track and be smooth.

Ideas?

Snippet demonstrating behavior:

```js
(function ( $ ) {

 $.fn.endless = function( options ) {
  var el = this;
  var originalHeight = el.children().first().outerHeight() * el.children().length;
  var dup = el.contents().clone();
  el.append(dup);

  el.scroll(function(){

   var scrollPosition = el.scrollTop();

   if( scrollPosition >= originalHeight ) {
    el.scrollTop(0);
   } else if (scrollPosition < 1) {
    el.scrollTop(el.outerHeight())
   }
  });

 };

}( jQuery ));

$('#mainmenu').endless();
```

```css
.rmenu {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 min-width: 50px;
 height: 200px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainmenu" class="rmenu">
   <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>
   <div>4</div>
   <div>5</div>
   <div>6</div>
   <div>7</div>
   <div>8</div>
   <div>9</div>
   <div>10</div>
   <div>11</div>
   <div>12</div>
   <div>13</div>
   <div>14</div>
   <div>15</div>
   <div>16</div>
   <div>17</div>
   <div>18</div>
   <div>19</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work well. It's more complex than I had anticipated, so perhaps someone can post a simpler solution.

```js
(function ( $ ) {
    
     $.fn.endless = function( options ) {
      var el = this;
      var originalHeight = el.children().first().outerHeight() * el.children().length;
      var $before = $("<span>", {id: "endless-before"});
      var $after = $("<span>", {id: "endless-after"});
      $before.append(el.contents().clone());
      $after.append(el.contents().clone());
      el.children().wrapAll($('<span>', {id: 'endless-original'}));
      el.prepend($before);
      el.append($after);
      var newHeight = el.children().first().outerHeight() * el.children().length;
      var beforeTop = $('#endless-before').offset().top;
      var originalTop = $('#endless-original').offset().top;
      var afterTop = $('#endless-after').offset().top;
      el.scrollTop(originalTop + 1);
    
      el.scroll(function(){
       var scrollPosition = el.scrollTop();
    
       if(scrollPosition > afterTop) {
        el.scrollTop(originalTop);
        console.log("Looping up");
       } else if (scrollPosition < originalTop) {
        el.scrollTop(afterTop);
        console.log("Looping down");
       }
      });
    
     };
    
    }( jQuery ));
    
$('#mainmenu').endless();
```

```css
body { overflow: hidden; }
.rmenu {
 position: absolute;
 right: -30px;
 min-width: 150px;
 height: 200px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainmenu" class="rmenu">
   <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>
   <div>4</div>
   <div>5</div>
   <div>6</div>
   <div>7</div>
   <div>8</div>
   <div>9</div>
   <div>10</div>
   <div>11</div>
   <div>12</div>
   <div>13</div>
   <div>14</div>
   <div>15</div>
   <div>16</div>
   <div>17</div>
   <div>18</div>
   <div>19</div>
  </div>
```